# Mailchimp update existing product with a batch C#

Tags: c#, product, mailchimp

I'm currently in the process of syncing our product data to MailChimp using their batch function. Now, I've succeeded in adding products (the initial upload), but I struggle to update existing products.

What I have tried is the following:

1) Created a new batch, added an operation with method "PUT" and POSTING it to their API. This gives no error on uploading the batch, but the batch result returns a "Method not allowed"

2) Created a new batch, added an operation with method "PUT" and PUTTING it to their API. This returns a "Method not allowed" on batch upload.

3) Created a new batch, added an operation with method "POST" and POSTING it to their API. This gives an error because the product already exists.

I'm using a custom build integration for mailchimp, that uses a normal HttpClient.

This is the code that builds the operation:

```
    var body = BuildProductBody(products.First());

    var method = GetMethod(products.First());

    batch.operations.Add(new SingleOperation
    {
        method = method,
        operation_id = "asd" + products.First().Id,
        path = string.Format("ecommerce/stores/{0}/products", GetStoreId(store)),
        body = body
    });
```

Did anyone succeed in updating products through their API?

Comment: Can you point us to the MailChimp documentation that talks about this functionality? Were you able to make it work using Postman? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: Mailchimp documentation: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/batches/

I havent tried Postman yet, I will do that in a moment